# Framework for a networked iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, api, rest, social-networking

I'm trying to build a basic social iOS app in the new iOS 6 beta as a proof-of-concept project to improve my iOS development skills. In essence I want to allow users to generate an account, store some info in the cloud, and then be able to pull their info (and that of their friends) into the device. I already have a front end roughed in on the device but I now need to start the networking component and am looking for suggestions for any libraries, frameworks, tutorials and/or guidelines to use.

I was thinking of building the server end with node.js and mongodb as I already have a RESTful API built on them which I can adapt to this task. Is this the best way to accomplish such an app? I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple more networking library suggestions:

1) AFNetworking - https://github.com/afnetworking/afnetworking . This is widely used (more so now that ASIHttpRequest has stopped development). It is modern and block-based. However, it is not ARC yet.

2) MKNetworkKit - https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKNetworkKit . Modern and ARC based.

I switched all my apps from ASIHttpRequest to AFNetworking and highly recommend it.

All the frameworks mentioned so far (ASIHttpRequest, RESTKit, AFNetworking, MKNetworkKit) will talk to a node.js/restful API backend just fine.

Comment: Thanks I'll give them a shot. Any suggestions on how to handle user validation (oAuth etc) on the RESTful side with node.js?

Answer (score 1):

The most common and popular libraries to handle network connections are ASIHTTPRequest: http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ and RESTKit: http://restkit.org . I am using RESTKit right now as a component of the Salesforce library. I used ASIHTTPRequest in the past and found it to be a very good library. I haven't used it in a while but i highly recommend it.

Edit: I would also reccomend CocoaRestClient to test your APIs.

Comment: Don't use ASIHTTPRequest, it's been officially abandoned.